# RELOAD privileges in order to flush hosts

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I was connected to a remote mysql server but after a few bad connections (due to automation) I was blocked from the server. I am trying to unblock myself.

A prompt suggested I perform a `mysqladin flush-hosts`

```
# This was done locally
$ mysql -h remote_host -u user_name
ERROR 1129 (HY000): Host 'remote_host' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'
$ mysqladmin flush-hosts
mysqladmin: refresh failed; error: 'Access denied; you need (at least one of) the RELOAD privilege(s) for this operation'
```

I get this message:

```
mysqladmin: refresh failed; error: 'Access denied; you need (at least one of) the RELOAD privilege(s) for this operation'
```

Because I am pretty new to mysql and mysql-workbench I am not sure how I can fix this issue.

I also tried to SSH into the `remote_host` and typed in the command `mysqladmin flush-hosts` but I get the error:

```
error: 'Access denied for user 'user1'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd link in Google on "mysql RELOAD privilege" - [FLUSH syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/flush.html):

> To execute FLUSH, you must have the [RELOAD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_reload) privilege.

The highlighted link says:

> The RELOAD privilege enables use of the FLUSH statement. It also
>   enables [mysqladmin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqladmin.html) commands that are equivalent to FLUSH operations: <...>

And, on that page, in turn, there's a [`--user` option](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqladmin.html#option_mysqladmin_user).

Comment: I don't see a RELOAD privilege in phpmyadmin.php for a database user.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, users can only be local (associated with one database) or global (associated with all databases). If you need your user account to flush a database to its associated data folder or directory (so you can save or restore the database, for example), then my experiments show that you cannot make your user be local. It must be global, but you can choose to enable only data manipulation privileges plus RELOAD to flush tables.

There seems to be no way in MySQL to have a strictly local database user have the ability to flush the tables only of its own database.